# Vector space "generated by" an abstract affine space

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, vector-spaces, terminology, affine-geometry

Given an affine space $A$, we can formally generate a vector space $V$ by points of $A$, subject to the affine relations among them found in $A$. In particular, if $a$ and $b$ are points of $A$, then $a + b$ will be defined as an element of $V$, and the middle point of the segment $[ab]$ will be $\frac{a}{2} + \frac{b}{2}$ with respect to the vector operations of $V$.

Does this construction have a standard name?
What has it been used for?

*Update.*

The construction I am interested in seems to be just a different formulation of the *Barycentric Calculus of Möbius*, see

1. Möbius, August Ferdinand (1827). [*Der barycentrische Calkul*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=_crYzOv_49QC).
2. Allardice, R. (1891).  [*The Barycentric Calculus of Möbius*](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/proceedings-of-the-edinburgh-mathematical-society/article/barycentric-calculus-of-mobius/235A89804289968FD4C285175D234A86). Proceedings of the Edinburgh Mathematical Society, 10, 2-21.

Comment: I did this construction in some handwritten notes in 1986, but I've never seen it in print. Do you have any references for it? (I know that seems like throwing your own question back at you!)

Comment: @CalumGilhooley, i do not have any reverences, it just looks like a useful construction to me.

Comment: @CalumGilhooley, i've discovered that this must be [The Barycentric Calculus of Möbius](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/proceedings-of-the-edinburgh-mathematical-society/article/barycentric-calculus-of-mobius/235A89804289968FD4C285175D234A86), published in 1827. I am still unaware of any "modern" treatment of the construction.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is called the "universal space" in Berger's *Geometry I*.

Comment: @Yai0Phah, thanks! Could you write it as an answer, please?